Java Spring expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations
Spring boot application throws No Qualifying bean of type available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. error at runtime.
Please find my code below.
SpringBoot version : 2.7.9
JDK 11
public class CatalogServiceImpl extends CatalogService.CatalogServiceImplBase {

    private final DataSourceHandler dataSourceHandlerDelegate;

    private final StorefrontServiceHelper storefrontServiceHelper

    CatalogServiceImpl ( DataSourceHandler dataSourceHandlerDelegate, 
    StorefrontServiceHelper storefrontServiceHelper) {
    this.dataSourceHandlerDelegate = dataSourceHandlerDelegate;
    this.storefrontServiceHelper = storefrontServiceHelper;
 }
}

public class StorefrontServiceHelper {

    private final CatalogServiceHelper catalogServiceHelper

     public StorefrontServiceHelper(CatalogServiceHelper catalogServiceHelper){
    this.catalogServiceHelper = catalogServiceHelper;
   }

 }

public class CatalogServiceHelper {

   private final DataSourceHandler dataSourceHandlerDelegate

   public CatalogServiceHelper(DataSourceHandler dataSourceHandlerDelegate) {
    this.dataSourceHandlerDelegate = dataSourceHandlerDelegate
   }

 }

public interface DataSourceHandler {

}

public class DataSourceHandlerDelegate implements DataSourceHandler {

    public DataSourceHandlerDelegate(DataSourceHandler dynamoDBDataSourceHandler){
    this.dynamoDBDataSourceHandler = dynamoDBDataSourceHandler
   }
 }

 public class AppConfig {

 @Bean
 DataSourceHandlerDelegate 
 dataSourceHandlerDelegate(@Qualifier("DataSourceHandlerDelegate") DataSourceHandler 
 dynamoDBDataSourceHandler){
  return new DataSourceHandlerDelegate(dynamoDBDataSourceHandler)
}

Getting below run time error :
2024-10-26 16:20:31,703 [thread="main" class="o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext" cid="" id="" dd_trace_id="" dd_span_id=""] Exception encountered during context initialization cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory. Unsatisfied Dependency Exception: Error creating bean with name 'catalogServiceImpl' defined in file [item-service/build/classes/java/main/com/item/grpc/CatalogServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory. UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storefrontServiceHelper' defined in file [item-service/build/classes/java/main/com/item/service/StorefrontServiceHelper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory. UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'catalogServiceHelper' defined in file [item-service/build/classes/java/main/com/item/service/CatalogServiceHelper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory. Unsatisfied DependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceHandlerDelegate' defined in class path resource [com/item/config/AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceHandlerDelegate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com..item.datasource.DataSourceHandler' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation. Qualifier (value="DataSourceHandlerDelegate")}


Looking to this:
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  DataSourceHandlerDelegate dataSourceHandlerDelegate(@Qualifier("DataSourceHandlerDelegate") DataSourceHandler dynamoDBDataSourceHandler) {
    return new DataSourceHandlerDelegate(dynamoDBDataSourceHandler);
  }
}

It means that to create the dataSourceHandlerDelegate is needed another a DataSourceHandler bean called DataSourceHandlerDelegate. I don't know if this is really what you may have in your context, but I suppose that the DataSourceHandler object that has to be managed through the delegate is qualified with another name, e.g. the dynamoDBDataSourceHandler that is referenced as the constructor parameter in the DataSourceHandlerDelegate class. Check your configuration for putting in the @Qualifier annotation the right name of the handler bean.

Looks like Bean not created. Similar issue i faced before , i clean the project and did the maven  install . refresh the project and check the .class file .

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
